# Why my iBook G4 superdrive spits out the Mac OS X Leopard Install Disk?

Tags: macos, leopard, books, optical-drive, powerpc

The SuperDrive of my late 2005 iBook G4 died, so I installed a new one. But now the new drive does not mount the Leopard Install Disk. But it mounts any other DVDs/CDs (music, movies). The disk mounts on my MacBook Pro. Can anyone answer me why it is happening ?

Comment: When does it *spits* it? Are you trying to boot from it or just trying to mount it on the desktop?

Comment: @Thecafremo - Both the times.

Comment: Is the Install Disk the one you got with the iBook G4, or perhaps from another computer? A MacBook Pro? If this is the case, the Install Disk might be for an **Intel Processor** while the G4 has not.

Comment: @Thecafremo that doesn't mean the DVD will be rejected, the installer just won't run. He's talking about a common issue of an optical drive refusing to spin a disk up, and ejecting it instead. I've yet to find a solution.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX Last time I tried to use an Install Disk devised for a different processor it did spit it out.